# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Помогите пожалуйста. Я новичёк в PHP, и не понимаю, что значит эта ошибка? Z пытаюсь сделать счётчик просмотров.
P.S = С SELECT всё работает. Но мне нужно обновить, а не прочитать.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test_db');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `articles` SET `views` = `views` + 1");
    $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $record['views'];
?>
```

Comment: И что ты ожидаешь в результате от UPDATE запроса? Он просто обновляет запись в таблице, но __ничего не выбирает__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то можно выполнить следующим образом:

```
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test_db');
// выбираем последнее значение просмотра из articles
   $record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT views FROM articles");
   $getviews = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record);
     $getview = $getviews['views'];
    // добавляем к просмотру + 1
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE articles SET views = $getview +1");
    // проверяем, что всё успешно
    $record = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT views FROM articles");
   $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($record);
    // в record будет + 1 просмотр от того, что был
   echo $record['views']; // т.е. выведет 2
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение.